# Convert String to Json to apply JSON Patch

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to take a request using postmon in for a json string to apply json patch. The issue is I am unable to convert the string to json one the data is posted via variable. Every time I do

```
JSON.parse(document);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

The Data which I am sending is the following

```
{"document":"{'baz': 'qux', 'foo': 'bar'}"}
```

via postman using a post method.

I am using req.body to get hand on post data

Comment: Why aren't you sending JSON ? You can just use `JSON.stringify` on an object.

Comment: this error means you are parse a string which is not stringified

Comment: Tried that it did not work the data is still in a string I will not be able to apple JSONPATCH. I need to take the input from user for JSON Data and Patch Data and send the Patched Data back to user.

Comment: JSON requires that properties and strings are quoted using double quotes `"` not single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"{'baz': 'qux', 'foo': 'bar'}" is not a valid json string.
```

Single quotes are not correctly formatted json so 
the parser will not accept single quote and will throw below error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

[image]

So to be able to parse that string as json you will need to replace ' quotes with " quotes using str.replace() before parsing

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {"document":"{'baz': 'qux', 'foo': 'bar'}"};
console.log(JSON.parse(data.document.replace(/'/g, '"')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `document` is already an `object` which points to the `document` global variable in `window`, and it's not a `string` so you can't parse it. That's why you will get :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

So if you has an `object` you need to stringify it before you can parse it, so use:

```
JSON.stringify(doc);
```

**Note:**

Note that if you have declared `document` as a variable, `document` is a bad name for a variable as it's already a global object name in the `window` which points to the current `document`, and using it will lead to many errors.

But if it's inside your `data`, it would be `JSON.parse(data)` as you are dealing with `data` object from your `response`.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = {"document":"{'baz': 'qux', 'foo': 'bar'}"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```